# VSCode suddenly stops being able to run .sql files

Tags: visual-studio-code, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm working with sql files using the Snowflake extension so that I can have version control on my queries. I've been having no issues with it for so long, and I did not change anything with my session parameters. However, today after connecting to Snowflake and logging in, I am unable to execute any query. `ctrl+enter` does not work, the run button doesn't work, and the small `execute` button above the queries are gone. My python notebooks still work and I can still use git, so I think this is isolated to my sql files.

I've tried opening the file outside the workspace, restarting vscode, restarting my device, all to no avail. I'm also avoiding uninstalling and reinstalling due to administrative restrictions on my device, so if there is anyone here who has experienced the same thing, would appreciate any help in solving this odd issue.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of the extension are you using? The issue should be resolved on the newest version, v0.8.2. (this was released <12 hours ago).